# How to use Image Mask with ListView

Tags: android, listview, mask

I have an activity that list data with listView with their row's images.

```
   String[] from = {"subject","img","description","id"};
        int[] to = {R.id.tv_subject,R.id.iv_pic, R.id.tv_details, R.id.hide_id};

       SimpleAdapter adapter = new   SimpleAdapter(ListViewActivity.this,searchResult,R.layout.listview, from, to);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My ListView.xml is :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/iv_pic"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"/>
<TextView 
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/tv_subject"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
    android:textSize="15sp"   
    android:textStyle="bold" />

   <LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal">
   <TextView 

    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/tv_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <TextView
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/hide_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

now I have a part of code that display image with mask:

```
  ImageView mImageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    ImageView mImageView1= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
    Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.c);
    Bitmap mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.poster);
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(result);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setXfermode( new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));
    mCanvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);
    mCanvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(null);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
```

I wish to display each image in listview with mask(each image is in a row if listview)

Answer (score 0):

In order to customize the inflation of your ListView (eg. set "masks") you have to subclass the SimpleAdapter you have created and override the `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method.

In that method you check the view that was clicked and inflate it appropriately, setting the ImageView's and TextViews that you desire. And also within that method you will fill in the data that corresponds to the view that is being inflated.

Check out [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_example) tutorial for more.